# Adiós Spanish.SE

Tags: discusión

[Deletion by someone outside the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334185/deletion-by-someone-outside-the-community)

A la petición de Diego, hice esta pregunta para entender por qué alguien de fuera de nuestra comunidad borraría mi respuesta.  Resultado: pregunta cerrada desde el inicio*.

Ya llevo años contestando preguntas por aquí pero tengo límites.  No me veo volviendo por aquí.

<sub><sub>*[walen: Cerrada como "off-topic" por [animuson♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) apenas 5 minutos después de ser preguntada. Reabierta dos horas después con los votos de [gnat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165773/gnat), [TylerH](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/253521/tylerh), [Robert Columbia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/336163/robert-columbia), [Josh Darnell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/168428/josh-darnell), [Ward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130540/ward). Aquí el [historial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/334185/revisions).]</sub></sub>

Comment: Son momentos raros e incómodos para todos, pero espero que podamos salir de ellos y volver a la normalidad. La comunidad es mejor contigo que sin ti.

Comment: Yo he puesto mi granito de arena ahí también vía comment. Decían algunos usuarios que era un tema demasiado sensible para usarlo en este juego. No creo que eso justifique borrar sin dejar un comentario de explicación, y menos sin pedirte que lo arreglases tú guifa primero. Eso sí, **por favor no te vayas**. La comunidad de Spanish.se y los que hacen caja (SE Inc) somos dos cosas distintas, y eres un usuario muy apreciado. Tengamos un poco más de paciencia a ver cómo evolucionan las cosas. Tarde o temprano SE Inc se tendrá que pronunciar.

Answer (score 5):

Personalmente creo que tu respuesta al TG, aunque un poco arisca para lo que nos tienes acostumbrados, no estaba mucho más allá en cuanto a "rudeza" de lo que lo está la mía. Por tanto no tenía mucho sentido borrarla.
Como aparente001, yo también pienso que el borrado pudo ser más por el *"screw you"* de la traducción, que por el propio "me la suda", pero eso se arreglaba con un edit ‍♂️
Hablando de edit: te he editado la respuesta para incluir un enlace al DLE mostrando la [definición de la expresión](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YdJpI2b#FQMumpu), por si sirve de algo. Quizá también podrías considerar usar "me suda la comunidad" en vez de "me la suda la comunidad"; sé que no es exactamente lo mismo, pero sigue reflejando el mismo nivel de indiferencia por parte del que suda ;)

En cuanto a la interferencia de mods externos... Comprendo que es "su" red y que tienen derecho a intervenir si piensan que los mods particulares de cada comunidad no están cumpliendo con las tareas que se les han delegado. Al fin y al cabo son los Community Manager y están para eso, para gestionar la comunidad en su conjunto, y para eso se les convierte en "super mods" de todos los stacks. Pueden quitar a un mod si creen que no lo hace bien, pueden poner de mod a otra persona, pueden convocar elecciones en un stack... y por supuesto pueden borrar contenido a su antojo. Son como los agentes de Matrix

Pero que lo comprenda no quiere decir que comparta la forma en que han actuado. Como usuarios de Spanish.SE, nos hemos tirado años adaptándonos a la idiosincrasia de este stack, a la manera de hacer las cosas aquí, y hemos interiorizado lo que aquí "se puede" y "no se puede" hacer. Y en base a eso, publicamos nuestros comentarios y respuestas.
Entonces, que de repente y por causas ajenas al stack, vengan personas ajenas al sitio y a nuestro estilo, y nos apliquen unos límites distintos a los que nosotros conocemos, me parece injusta.
Seguramente si los posts los hubieran borrado nuestros propios mods, el debate sería otro. Pero no es el caso.

Sea como sea, guifa, estamos hablando de **abandonar una comunidad... porque alguien ajeno a la comunidad ha llegado y ha hecho algo contrario a lo que suele hacer la comunidad**. No sé, no lo veo.

Personalmente creo que no merece la pena abandonar Spanish.SE por algo así. Cuando se calmen un poco las aguas, los CM volverán a pasar de nosotros como siempre, pero nosotros seguiremos aquí con el buen rollo habitual y nuestra manera de hacer las cosas. ¿Te lo vas a perder?

No te vayas :(

Comment: Iba a poner mi propia respuesta, pero creo que esta resume suficientemente bien mis sentimientos, así que simplemente añado un par de comentarios: Yo he votado +1, no porque crea que Guifa (o cualquiera) deba irse a la luz de los acontecimientos, sino porque creo que es una pregunta para nuestro MEta interesante y que merece debatirse. No sé hasta qué punto JNat tomándose libertades en nuestro stack es consecuencia de la "huelga de mods". Comparto en que la gestión de este particular es acorde con la del incidente que motivó este TG (penosa) [...].

Comment: ...Borrar sin dar una explicación viene a decir que alguien puede imponer de qué se habla y de qué no. No la es la _ejecución_ más brillante para solucionar un problema, cuando el problema que motiva a este otro es la regulación de la libertad de expresión.

Answer (score 3):

I feel partially responsible, having written (a) the back-translation, and (b) an even more out-there answer to the Translation Golf game than the one you wrote.  I fear my answer may have been the act that triggered the deletions.  Maybe my provocative back-translation played a role.

The dark stuff I was writing (e.g. one version of my answer, which was only live for a short time, included the phrase "Heil Hitler," used sarcastically) was coming partly from my frustration with the Monica Cellio incident, and partly from frustration with that sad topic being used as the text for what is normally a lighthearted, fun game.  You probably recall that I voted to close the question, with a public comment below the question that explained why.

Weirdly and inexplicably, when the hit man, employee @jnat, deleted my answer and yours, he (I say "he" judging from the photo in his profile) also deleted the comment I had written explaining my vote to close.  Fedorqui has told me that jnat is fluent in Spanish -- but I'm still concerned that my back-translation may have made your answer appear more provocative to him.

The two things that have been bothering me the most about the Monica Cellio incident are

1. People of all stripes and opinions have been reacting in a split second, going zero to sixty, leaving no time for reflection.  I understand -- heck, they're angry and their fight-or-flight response has been triggered.  But this zero-to-sixty pace doesn't allow for the time, reflection and communication needed for conflict resolution.
2. The head honchos, whoever they are, who are crying "Off with her head" (in case anyone doesn't recognize it, this is a quote from the Queen of Hearts in *Alice in Wonderland*), are providing no public explanations of their positions and actions, and are providing no date for providing public explanations.

Guifa, this is a small site.  It means a lot to those of us who participate here.  It wouldn't be the same without you.  If you feel bitter now and need to take a break, I'll understand.  But I would like to ask you to allow yourself some time to see if some healing is possible.  Rather than going zero to sixty yourself, I invite you to show all the hotheads out there what it looks like, when dealing with outrageous behavior from others, to take to take a few deep breaths, walk away for a while, and take some time before deciding definitively on a particular action.

(With difficulty, I've been working on learning to do that, in my reactions to provocative behavior from one of my children, who has Tourette Syndrome, and in my reactions to outrageous behavior on the part of teachers and administrators who have, basically, tortured the child.  I've been finding that it really does help to step away and then come back to address the problems with more equanimity.)

I don't want the role I played to result in your being gone for good.

And wouldn't that amount to letting the folks who set off this firestorm win?

Answer (score 0):

*Reposting here the answer written by @jnat at SE Meta one hour ago*

> You already got a bit of context from the comments as to *why* I
>   deleted the answer. Two things worth clearing up:
>
> - Yours wasn't the only answer I deleted;
> - The first thing I did before touching *any* of the posts was to hop into a chat room with the site's mods, to talk about how to approach
>     the post. I saw this was a recurrent event for y'all, so thought it'd
>     be best to get some context beforehand. Furthermore, as a non-native
>     English speaker, I'm also sensitive to the stuff that can get lost in
>     translation.
>
> I determined that, despite the choice of a sensitive topic in a
>   sensitive time, letting y'all vent in a humorous way might be better
>   than stomping on it. So me and the moderators deliberated that the
>   clearly offensive or "Meta discussion-y" answers, at least, had no
>   place there — which even lead to a warning at the top of the question,
>   saying so. The mods left a comment, and I deleted the answers — these
>   actions were done in tandem.
>
> As you pointed out, the translation into Spanish itself had no
>   problems — it was the translation back into English that was the
>   offending bit. I didn't pick up on that, but you subsequently
>   corrected it.
>
> I have, in the meantime, talked with the mods again: I trust them to
>   be able to moderate the post on their own. That means I deferred to
>   them on whether to undelete the answer or not, based on your edit
>   (they've since undeleted it). It also means I trust them to be able to
>   delete the answers that don't abide by the "strictly language
>   proficiency show-off" rule at the top of the question.

Answer (score 0):

[La respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334246/621007) no me convence y me he cambiado el nombre de usuario como primera fase de salida (no solo en Spanish.SE pero en los demás). Los que saben el nombre de usuario podrán encontrarme en otras partes de la Web con el antiguo usuario, sobre todo en lo relacionado con Perl 6 / Raku.

Si en el venidero próximo veo que reconoce que lo se ha hecho mal (no solo repasar meramente lo que ha hecho)¹ y e indica cómo eso no va a pasar en el futuro, tal vez vuelva, caso no, borro la cuenta completa y definitivamente.

---

<sup>1. Por ejemplo, de haber borrado sin ver el historial, de haber borrado sin dejar que el moderador activo lo hiciese, de considerar una frase que en inglés tampoco es tan fuerte obligase un borrado automático e instantáneo, y de dar un razonamiento erróneo (porque es evidente que ninguna de las seis razones estipuladas aplicaba a la respuesta); y que Animuson se cerró la pregunta repentinamente a pesar de que se trataba de exactamente lo que está «on-topic» en Meta.</sup>

Comment: Gusto de verte (parcialmente) por estos rumbos, user072....  //  ¿Cuál respuesta no te convence?  La mía?  La de @jnat en Meta?  Otra? // Tengo un poquitito de información más, ojalá y pueda postearla hoy o mañana.

Comment: @aparente001 la de JNat.  No te culpo, no vi nada malo en tu traducción.

Comment: Gracias, asi me tranquilizo un poquito.  Paciencia, por favor, tengo algo que tal vez va a ayudar.

Comment: Yo tengo que entonar mi parte del mea culpa y pedirte disculpas por lo sucedido. Debido a mi estatus de ["inactivo como protesta"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334127/356575) me desentendí de este tema cuando apareció JNat, y tal vez debería haber atendido a la conversación para ver qué quería hacer una persona ajena en nuestro stack. Creo que Charlie defendió a más no poder que no se tocase absolutamente nada, pero al final tuvo que negociar quitar las partes más conflictivas (que no eran tuyas, para más inri). Entiendo que el cierre de la pregunta Meta no hizo sino echar sal a la herida

Comment: @Diego tampoco tienes por qué implicarte.  Lo ocurrido es por los de SE, y son ellos los que han de disculparse.  Pero siendo sincero, hubiese tenido de tomar un descanso bastante largo porque en los próximos meses tengo que acabar la tesis sí o sí y preparar algunas ponencias para congresos.  Lo acaecido solo me ha hecho la decisión más fácil.

Comment: @user0721090601 - No tengo permiso todavia de compartir la informacion que tengo, pero ojala y ma~nana si.  Suerte con la tesis y las ponencias.

Comment: I have permission now to share.  I think this may mean that there actually was some cooperation from one of our site's moderators in the deletions.  I still don't completely understand what happened, but here it is: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/99394/2019/10/2.

Comment: @walen - I didn't realize anyone else had seen it -- there was no indication of that in any of the discussions that I saw.  I asked fedorqui for permission out of courtesy.  I'm not certain how to interpret it -- but I wasn't sure how he'd feel about it coming out in the open.  The way things have unfolded makes me feel like I'm standing on an ice floe....

Comment: I was editing my post, looking for an alternative to "Ja wohl."   I read fedorqui's comment saying I should stick to the rules of the game.  I asked him to say more clearly what he thought I should do.  I thought he might suggest I delete or edit the post.  He replied with another vague comment -- and then boom, my post was gone, my comment explaining my vote to close was gone, no explanation; I couldn't figure out who the heck jnat was and why he was going at the page with a dull machete. Another sarcastic post that didn't stick to the rules was still there -- the one with 39 characters...

Comment: ... and I thought, in an autocracy, when the autocrats are running scared, they strike in an arbitrary way.  But later, in the chat, it seemed that maybe fedorqui was saying that he put the ribbons around the trees that he thought needed to be felled, for the woodcutter to come and take care of later.  In a way, that helped; in a way, it didn't.  I'm a reasonable person, and open to suggestions and guidance.  I experienced that hit man style of moderation at another SE site several years ago.  It wasn't pleasant.

Comment: guifa / @user0721090601 esperaremos con ansia verte por aquí. Muchos ánimos en el enclaustramiento para terminar la tesis, si necesitas gente para la presentación avisa e iremos encantados :)

Comment: Just wanted to confirm what was @JNat saying in [their answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334246/209901): Jnat was pinged by other mods (or users, I don't know) about [a version of an answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/revisions/31611/3) and entered in our private chat to talk about it with Spanish.SE mods. It is not abnormal to get a CM here and there on specific situations (we've had this on other times, two or three maybe). We checked that answer and we also saw guifa's to be borderline, so I posted a comment suggesting to tone it down. (cont.)

Comment: Then JNat deleted it and I honestly saw it as a temporary situation while the answer was being toned down. I am sorry for not foreseeing the damage this would cause and the perception it would have among the community members.